# Samba configuration file location

Tags: 14.04, networking, nautilus, samba

I have setup samba share in Ubuntu 14.04, by using the Local Network Share option in nautilus and I am able to successfully access the shared folder from other computers in my home.

What I can't figure out is, where nautilus stores samba share configuration. I expected it to be in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`, but the shared folder is not listed there. I also found another config file in `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`, but it doesn't list the shared folder either.

I would appreciate it, if someone could help me figure out the location of samba configuration file in Ubuntu.

Comment: Not quite sure, but check `/var/lib/samba/`.

Answer (score 11):

The share definition is located at /var/lib/samba/usershares when you create the share with the Nautilus GUI interface.  The main Samba file share server (smbd and nmbd) is configured at /etc/samba/smb.conf.  Root created shares are also configured at /etc/samba/smb.conf.

```
root created shares = /etc/samba/smb.conf
usershares = /var/lib/samba/usershares
```